# Remove "Dragging" graphic from JQUERY-UI Sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, html-table, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a table in which I am using Jquery UI sortable.

I am using a place holder which is a clone of the item being moved.

```
 $("#sortable tbody").sortable({
     items: 'tr[id!=noSort]', start: function (event, ui) {
                clone = $(ui.item[0].outerHTML).clone();
             },
             placeholder: {
                 element: function (clone, ui) {
                     return $('<tr class="OddTableRow move"">' + clone[0].innerHTML + '</tr>');
                 },
                 update: function () {
                     return;
                 }
             }
        });
```

This is working great, however, I just want to see the place holder moving up and down the table and not the table row moving with my mouse all over the screen.  Has anyone ever tried to do this?  Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `cursor` option along with the rest of your code, and set it to `none`

would build you a fiddle but you didn't provide html

```
 $("#sortable tbody").sortable({
     cursor: "none",
     items: 'tr[id!=noSort]', start: function (event, ui) {
                clone = $(ui.item[0].outerHTML).clone();
             },
     placeholder: {
                 element: function (clone, ui) {
                     return $('<tr class="OddTableRow move"">' + clone[0].innerHTML + '</tr>');
                 },
                 update: function () {
                     return;
                 }
     }

  });
```

Comment: huh, i could have sworn i tried that.  Oh well I ended up using helper and setting it to an unpopulated table row.  Thanks though, this looks like much better code